# pyqt call ui in another py file

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I use qtDesigner and uic to get a ui.py file,and I want call the ui variable in the Output.py file.I import the get_ui function which return ui

It appear Nameerror when i run the demo.What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!
[ui.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgPfT.png)

Comment: Post the actual code in the question, along with the full traceback

Comment: Thank your help ,I find the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The export from QtDesigner has a class definition (similar to this):

```
class Ui_Form(object):
(...)
```

When you import the `ui.py` into another file, you do this:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog
from ui import Ui_Form  # ui because of ui.py, Ui_Form because of the class name

class AppWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        # more definitions (buttons etc.) come here, example follows:
        self.ui.ExistingButton.clicked.connect(self.pressed_okay)

    def pressed_okay(self):
        self.accept()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AppWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

That's the minimum to get your GUI going.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I want to call the member of ui,for example ui.button.your answer create a new object .

Comment: Your `__init__` seems to be incorrect. Either call `super(AppWindow, self).__init__()` or `QDialog.__init__(self)`.

Comment: I copied it from a program of mine that is, in fact, working. I know there are several ways to do the `__init__`. I got this one off a YouTube tutorial, I think.

@CinderellaM: If you want to call your button you do that inside the `__init__`, e.g. `self.ui.PushButton.clicked.connect(self.function_that_does_something)`

Comment: Thank your help ,I find the reason:if __name__=="__main__".because of this,Other module can't call the code in it.Icreate a new object and inherits the ui object ,It works well